# android coordinatorLayout+tabLayout(bottom)+viewPager is giving error

Tags: android

I am using coordinator layout as my root layout for the activity(activity_main for which the layout code is below). In it i have a

- AppBarLayout inside having a toolbar
- ViewPager
- TabLayout

The problem is my viewpager has a recyclerView/cardview describing a list of data and the very last element in the list is getting covered by the tabLayout. Any solution ? (currently min-version to work with is jellyBean but this following for lollipop)
[click here to view screen with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XazKQ.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/container"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following properties to your recyclerView and check

```
<RecyclerView
  android:clipToPadding="false"
  android:paddingBottom="50dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your having this problem is because the `TabLayout` is drawing in front of `ViewPager`. Now there are multiple ways to solve this but one of the easier ways would be to wrap your `ViewPager` and `TabLayout` in a `Relativelayout` and limit the `ViewPager` from drawing behind the `TabLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tab_layout"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: its taking the tabLayout out of the screen completely

Comment: can you share some other solution which you say are useful?

Comment: @gauravarora  Just remove the 
        `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` from `RelativeLayout` and if that doesn't work then try adding 
        `android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"` to `RelativeLayout`